# Sequence.compactMap equivalent for tuples with optional values

Tags: swift

Chaining sequence operations and using `compactMap` to remove optionals makes for a clean-looking code, like so:

```
let images: [UIImage] = strings
   .compactMap { URL(string: $0) }
   .compactMap { try? Data(contentsOf: $0) }
   .compactMap { UIImage(data: $0) }
```

But if I want to get a sequence of tuples `(URL, UIImage)` at the end, then `compactMap` doesn't help to remove optionals.

One approach I found is using `Optional.map`, and it works, but not as cleanly as above.

```
let pairs: [(URL, UIImage)] = strings
   .compactMap { URL(string: $0) }
   .compactMap { url in 
       (try? Data(contentsOf: url)).map { (url, $) }
   }
   .compactMap { t in
      UIImage(data: t.1).map { (t.0, $0) }
   }
```

Is there a cleaner way (`??` operator overload maybe) to achieve the above?

Comment: Initializers are already named closures, so you don’t need to make those three new closures.

Comment: @Jessy, you mean, I could do `.compactMap(UIImage(data:))`? Sure, but I was trying to show a parallel with the code below. And I also don't know how it would have worked with the throwing `Data(contentsOf:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the last two compact maps can be combined:

```
compactMap { try? UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: $0)) }
```

The word `try` doesn't have to be immediately before the throwable call. It's just that any throwable call has to be in the scope of a `try` expression.

Now since you want a tuple, you'd do:

```
compactMap { ($0, try? UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: $0))) }
```

However, `compactMap` expects a `(URL, UIImage)?`, rather than a `(URL, UIImage?)`. There is really no way to transform one to the other other than pattern matching. You can write an `Optional` initialiser for this purpose:

```
extension Optional {
    init<T, U>(_ tuple: (T?, U?)) where Wrapped == (T, U) {
        switch tuple {
        case (let t?, let u?):
            self = (t, u)
        default:
            self = nil
        }
    }
}

let images = strings
   .compactMap { URL(string: $0) }
   .compactMap {
       Optional(($0, try? UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: $0))))
   }
```

Alternatively, if you are being lazy, you can use `map` on the `try` expression, similar to what you did:

```
compactMap { url in 
    (try? UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: url))).map { 
        (url, $0) 
    } 
}
```

But I find this less readable.

Comment: Yeah, the first approach is a good idea. Is there any way to do what you did with `mapOptionalTuple` but by doing an operator overload, so something could be done: `(value, optional) ?? nil`

Comment: `public extension Optional`